# Google Postmaster Feedback Loop identifier is count 0

Tags: amazon-sns, amazon-ses, feedback-loop, google-postmaster

In google postmaster for my domain in last 120 days Feedback Loop identifier count 0 but spam rate is variable for each day from 0.1% to to Max of 1.5%. I am sending more that 5000 emails per day. Also I am utilising Amazon SES to send the emails and I am not getting any spam notification from AWS SNS. I am getting delivery notifications. I suspect that my gmail FBL is not working and I am not sure How can I debug that.

Any help is highly appreciated.

I have validated spf, dkim and dmarc records. Also I sent an email in my gmail account and marked it as spam but did not get the complaint notification from SES

Comment: Same here, I have my own server, and less than 1000 emails. Reading the help "In order to prevent spoofing of the Feedback-ID, the traffic being sent to Gmail needs to be DKIM signed by a domain owned (or controlled) by the sender, after the addition of this header. This domain should be added and verified to the Gmail Postmaster Tools, so the sender can access the FBL data."  Do you think that the order, I believe that I first verify and then add the header, can be importan?

Answer (score 0):

Google and Yahoo had changed the policies for who are sending more than 5000/emails and you can check this information https://ops.team/dmarc and https://ops.team/blog/google-e-yahoo-comunicacao-mais-segura-2/

Comment: I have checked the link sent a test email and it is saying that SPF valid, DKIM valid, DMARC valid. I am getting spam reports from yahoo and other platforms and not getting any complaint from gmail.

Comment: Send the header here or send me in my email bruno@ops.team